how to edit androidmanifest.xml in Qt
I ran into a problem: changes set in AndroidMainfest.xml , are not specified in the build directory. AndroidManifest.xml was created with other parameters.
I created AndroidManifest.xml use the "create template" button in the project build menu. After that, I registered the directory with AnroidMainfest.xml and other android files in the Cmake project file.
Cmake I am using the Qt version 6.7.0.
My AndroidManifest.xml file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="org.qtproject.example.Shopot" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <!-- %%INSERT_PERMISSIONS -->
    <!-- %%INSERT_FEATURES -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>
    <application android:name="org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:label="Shopot" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:allowBackup="true" android:fullBackupOnly="false" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density" android:label="Shopot" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.extract_android_style" android:value="minimal"/>
        </activity>

        <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.qtprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/qtprovider_paths"/>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>


I had hoped that I would find an answer in this topic https://forum.qt.io/topic/152024/android-app-doesn-t-run
as a result, I found a link to such an interesting problem https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-27119 .

Well i Googled the solution today Qt/Android/CMake: Custom AndroidManifest.xml not taken into account
I added these lines of code to cmake:


set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/android CACHE INTERNAL "")





set_target_properties(Shopot PROPERTIES
#    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.Shopot
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
    QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android

)



